# Como atribuir dois valores no ng-click?

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho esse corpo html que inverterá a variavel booleana `d.expandedBlog` quando for clicada. Está funcionando normalmente.

```
<div class="article-blog-icon-comment">
    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o article-blog-menu-topbar" 
    ng-click="d.expandedBlog = !d.expandedBlog" pr-expand-article="d.article.uid"
    expandedBlog="d.expandedBlog"></i>
</div>
```

Porém agora quero que o mesmo corpo html também inverta a variavel `d.expanded`.

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
<div class="article-blog-icon-comment">
    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o article-blog-menu-topbar" 
    ng-click="d.expandedBlog = !d.expandedBlog, d.expanded = !d.expanded" 
    pr-expand-article="d.article.uid"
    expandedBlog="d.expandedBlog" expanded="d.expanded"></i>
</div>
```

Mas está dando erro de sintaxe, não conheço a sintace para fazer este tipo de coisa. O que poderia ser feito aqui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode declarar mais de um comando de modo inline na diretiva `ng-click` separando os comandos com `;`, assim como se tivesse escrevendo no código normal:

```
[...]
ng-click="d.expandedBlog = !d.expandedBlog; d.expanded = !d.expanded" 
[...]
```

Porém, aconselho que você considere escrever uma função no controller para realizar esses comandos para maior claridade.

Comment: +1! Talvez seja válido comentar que expressões `ng-click` são interpretadas normalmente pelo parser do angularJs, razão pela qual você pode criar sequências discretas de expressões. Também concordo que uma função seria o melhor lugar para agregar estas ações.